# Are there any differences between Sideloading and Office 365 admin center preview manifest files

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, office365api, office-js

Are there any differences between the contents of a manifest file used for sideloading (local file share) and Office 365 admin center preview?
I have a fully working add-in hosted on SharePoint, and am currently using file share "Trusted add-ins catalogue" approach (sideloading).
I have asked our SharePoint rep to load the add-in into Office 365 admin center preview, but the "Apps for Office" tool responds that the manifest is not valid.

[image: Apps For Office pane]

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
          <Id>C058EB6E-F7CA-4586-832D-AD46F3BD3201</Id>
          <Version>1.3</Version>
          <ProviderName>Demo</ProviderName>
          <DefaultLocale>EN-US</DefaultLocale>
          <DisplayName DefaultValue="Rapid Component Add-in"/>
          <Description DefaultValue="Demo Rapid Component Add-in service live"/>
         <AppDomains>
          <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>
          <AppDomain>https://eadadfs.acompany.com</AppDomain>
          </AppDomains>
          <IconUrl DefaultValue=
            "https://acompanyportal.sharepoint.com/sites/ComponentAssembler/Shared%20Documents/RapidComponentLive/Images/logo.png"/>
          <Hosts>
            <Host Name="Document"/>
            <Host Name="Workbook"/>
          </Hosts>
          <DefaultSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://acompanyportal.sharepoint.com/sites/ComponentAssembler/Shared%20Documents/RapidComponentLive/generated.aspx"/>
          </DefaultSettings>
          <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
        </OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are differences. When you load manifest from a fileshare some errors are skipped and the manifest still loads; you can get more insight into that using [RuntimeLogging](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/use-runtime-logging-to-debug-manifest). When you load the manifest to the Add-in catalog (SP-based which doesn't support add-in commands btw) or the Admin Center Preview (O365) a full schema validation is also performed and that is why you see some errors.  Validate your manifest against the schema and/or use RuntimeLogging to see what is the error (e.g. putting IconUrl before AppDomains node should work).

BTW, the screenshot you uploaded is NOT of the [admin center preview](https://support.office.com/en-IE/article/Deploy-Office-Add-ins-in-the-Office-365-admin-center-preview-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f) but the SP-based Add-in catalog. If your intention is to try the preview make sure your admin is uploading it into the right place.

Comment: You are a star! Thanks - it is the <Iconurl DefaultValue= parameter, It needed to be moved to before the <AppDomains>